# cracking krb5 passwords (des3-hmac-sha1 and des-cbc-crc )

Tags: password-cracking, hmac, sha, kerberos, des

I'm trying to audit kerberos passwords. The available formats are des3-hmac-sha1 and des-cbc-crc but I cannot find a possibility/a tool to crack them. For other hash-types I used John the Ripper, but it seems to fail in this case. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

John the Ripper has community-supplied patches that appear to help with this.  For example, see:

- [A discussion on the John mail list](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2010/06/24/5)
- [The bleeding-jumbo branch](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/tree/bleeding-jumbo) of John the Ripper's Github repo, including [README-krb5-18-23](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/README-krb5-18-23) and the Kerberos modules in [src](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/tree/bleeding-jumbo/src).